# tab extension in Yii is needed

Tags: tabs, yii

I want to show 3 divs as a tabular box in a Yii-based project.

Does Yii framework have a build-in extension for Tabs ? Or I have to write my own extension for it?

Comment: does this do what you're after: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CJuiTabs?

Comment: Wow again Stu ! yes that is what I really need. Why do you post your answer as a comment Stu?

Comment: npo probs! Yii has a tonne of nifty bits integrated into its Zii widgets. I've added that as an answer for ya

Comment: thank you Stu. please put an answer instead of a comment. a question with a accepted mark will help who has the same question more that a helpful flag comment. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yii has integrated the JUITabs from jQuery nicely, CJuiTabs widget: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CJuiTabs